# .htaccess opencart redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I just migrate my site from asp to opencart. In .htaccess I would like to do some redirect so that my customer can use back the old link to access

inside .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /contact.asp http://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/contact_us
redirect 301 /downloads.asp http://www.example.com/downloads
```

For Contact Us that work perfectly, however, for the downloads url, it didn't work correct.
when I access to `http://www.example.com/downloads.asp` it will redirect to `http://www.example.com/downloads?_route_=downloads.asp`
and Opencart show it is page not found.
For the `http://www.example.com/downloads` we had set SEO friendly URL in the backend system.

We able to access with

http://www.example.com/information/downloads

http://www.example.com/downloads

but we not able to access with normal link

http://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/downloads

The folowing is my full .htaccess

```
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

redirect 301 /contact.asp http://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/contact_us
redirect 301 /downloads.asp http://www.example.com/downloads
```

============ANOTHER TESTING========================

I did some testing on this on my localhost I found out it is a quit interesting result. However, my problem still haven't solve.

I run the .htaccess from http://localhost/example and http://example (added virtual directory)

For http://localhost/example

```
redirect 301 /example/downloads.asp http://localhost/example/downloads/
```

and

For http://example

```
redirect 301 /downloads.asp http://example/downloads/
```

Then I tried, redirect to my live version link, from localhost (http://example)

```
redirect 301 /downloads.asp http://www.example.com/downloads/
```

I access to http://example/downloads.asp

The browser redirect to me

[http://www.example.com/downloads?*route*=downloads.asp](http://www.example.com/downloads?_route_=downloads.asp)

**NOTED**

In LIVE version, I did not added any redirect code **[VERY SURE FOR THIS]**

But in Live version, I am to access directly with enter

http://www.example.com/downloads

I am not sure why from localhost redirect 301 to live version will come out

[http://www.example.com/downloads?*route*=downloads.asp](http://www.example.com/downloads?_route_=downloads.asp)

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution Found:
**.htaccess redirect 301 working with opencart v1.5.4.1**

Additional code needed for... (and credits of this fix):
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/142
... replace contents of:
- catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php
- system/library/url.php

Redirect Fine:
RewriteRule contacto http:....com/index.php?route=information/contact [R=301,L]

Redirect Not Working:
redirect 301 contacto http:....com/index.php?route=information/contact

Verified.

Comment: I replaced `seo_url.php` and `url.php` - but what I need to write to the `htaccess`?

Answer (score 3):

Put it in front of router. Also add $ after .asp and ^ in front.

```
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

redirect 301 ^contact.asp$ http://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/contact_us
redirect 301 ^downloads.asp$ http://www.example.com/downloads

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Why don't you redirect contact to `/information/contact_us` instead of `index.php?route=information/contact_us` ?

Comment: because in opencart, there is no option for this. Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: I changed to your code, when I access to http://www.example.com/downloads.asp, it did not redirect on it, it still remind on the same link http://www.example.com/downloads.asp. Maybe you want try download opencart and test it out.

Comment: I tested in my localhost with
redirect 301 /example/downloads.asp http://localhost/example/downloads it work perfectly, but not in live version.

Comment: Try with.. `RewriteRule ^downloads.asp$ http://www.example.com/downloads [R=301,L]`

Comment: @webarto please have a look my question again, I added more example. I am not sure is my web server problem or what.

Comment: I tested your code, it not really work, I add before the index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA], the download page is work, but all other page with index.php break. If I add after the the line put it the last line, not different with added it or not. Really thanks for your help ya. I really .htaccess beginner

Answer (score 1):

You can try a **"?"** at the end of the redirect url if it is not present there like 2nd url(it worked for me) :

```
redirect 301 /contact.asp http://www.example.com/index.php?route=information/contact_us
redirect 301 /downloads.asp http://www.example.com/downloads?
```